# Why can't filecontents work in a macro

Tags: filecontents

I am trying to output some text in a file. I use `filecontents` and it works nicely. However, if I put the `filecontents` environment inside a macro, it only ouputs the comments but not the text when the macro is called.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.abc}
this gets in the file
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\toto}{
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.def}
this won't...
\end{filecontents}
}

\begin{document}

    \toto

\end{document}
```

I also tried using the `filecontents` in the `\AtEndDocument` hook, but again, nothing is found in the file. To that end, I added in the preamble of the above code

```
  \AtEndDocument{
    \typeout{AtEndDocument is being executed}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.ghi}
      this won't either...
    \end{filecontents}
  }
```

In all three cases, I have the warning saying that the file is created/replaced:

```
LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file xxx.ghi
```

Anyone has any clue what is going on? How this could be corrected so that contents gets to the files?

Comment: Well, the `filecontents` is supposed to only be used in the preamble, so writing it at the end of the document seems likely to fail. You are probably better off writing to an external file directly (or using a specialized [package](https://www.ctan.org/topic/io-mgmt)).

Comment: @jon egreg told me it should be used only before `\documentclass`.

Comment: @cfr -- That was the official recommendation, but it *does* work in the preamble as is now noted (cf. §.8.11 of *LaTeX2e*).  Of course, loading the `filecontents` package is usually recommended beyond the most simple applications....

Comment: @jon It doesn't always work in the preamble. It was because it didn't for me that egreg told me it should come prior to that with `\RequirePackage{}` if necessary. It depends on the content of the file.

Comment: @cfr -- Interesting. Is this a question here? And is that true even with the package? And should the (admittedly unofficial [not official as I miswrote!]) LaTeX2e manual maintainers be informed of this? As far as I remember, it *used* to be said that the `filecontents` environement should only be used in the way you say....

Comment: @jon Unless it has changed quite recently. I don't know how it applies to the environment without the package. I was using the package. It was a question here. However, I have no idea what it was about or if I had the problem in trying to answer a question or what. (I doubt that was the topic of the question.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're better off creating an output stream that you append stuff to; [`newfile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfile) provides this functionality:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,newfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.abc}
this gets in the file \jobname.abc
\end{filecontents*}

\newoutputstream{mystream}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.def}{mystream}
\newcommand{\toto}{%
  \addtostream{mystream}{this will be written to \jobname.def.}%
}

\begin{document}

Some text. \toto

\end{document}
```

The written files - `\jobname.abc` and `\jobname.def` - contain the following:

- `latex_stuff.abc`

  > this gets in the file latex_stuff.abc.
- `latex_stuff.def`

  > this will be written to latex_stuff.def.

Comment: The answer of @egreg explains well the cause of the problem, but this answer gave a neat alternative which could be expanded to solve my problem. Thanks Werner

Comment: \jobname is not expanded in the contents of abc (created with `filecontents*`), it seems.

Answer (score 13):

There are various reasons why it fails.

First and most important reason: when tokens are absorbed as the argument to another command, *including* `\newcommand` and `\AtEndDocument`, they receive their category code (if not control sequences) and endlines are converted to spaces or `\par` tokens.

When `\begin{filecontents}` is being processed, several changes are made, which are quite similar to what happens for `verbatim` (not completely the same); for instance you don't want that the backslash maintains its usual meaning, nor you want that an endline is converted to a space.

For this reason, the closing `\end{filecontents}` which TeX looks for is *not* 15 tokens

```
\end • { f • i • l • e • c • o • n • t • e • n • t • s • }
```

but 18:

```
\ • e • n • d • { f • i • l • e • c • o • n • t • e • n • t • s • }
```

where the backslash and the braces have category code 12; actually the lookup also includes the endline (which must be an active character, with a very particular meaning).

There are several other issues, particularly in connection with non ASCII characters.

Can this be corrected? Not in full generality.

Chances are that you don't really need `filecontents`, because writing a  file, with a given content, at the beginning or at the end of processing should not make any difference. So probably you're looking at the wrong tool for what you have in mind.

Comment: Could you explain the significance of category code 12? To me, category codes are a mysterious black box supposed to explain any kind of strange behaviour. (But maybe there's another question you could link that part of the explanation to instead? I suspect the answer might be too large for this answer, even just asking about code 12.)